# Org babel print elisp variable

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using org, I'd like to execute Lisp code which prints the value of a variable into a results block. E.g. I'm trying to print the value of `org-babel-default-header-args`.

I've tried this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports both
(print 'org-babel-default-header-args)
#+END_SRC


#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports both
(org-babel-default-header-args)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports both
(symbol-value 'org-babel-default-header-args)
#+END_SRC
```

The closest thing I've gotten to work is this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :exports both
(describe-variable 'org-babel-default-header-args)
#+END_SRC
```

But that prints out some extra text. I'd like to literally just print the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the value of a variable `foo`, use

```
(print foo)
```

*without* quoting it. Quote inhibits evaluation: that's exactly what you don't want to do here.